# Why does SymPy not work properly with real numbers?

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to evaluate an infinite sum in SymPy. While the first expression is calculated the way I expect it, SymPy seems to have trouble with the second expression.

```
from sympy import *
n = symbols('n')
print Sum((2)**(-n), (n, 1, oo)).doit()
print Sum((0.5)**(n), (n, 1, oo)).doit()
```

Results in:

```
1
Sum(0.5**n, (n, 1, oo))
```

I assume that the reason is that I am using a float number instead of an integer value.

Is there a way to approximate the sum instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs:](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/concrete.html#concrete-functions-reference)

> If it cannot compute the sum, it returns an unevaluated Sum object.

Another way to do this would be:

```
In [40]: Sum((Rational(1,2))**(n), (n, 1, oo)).doit()
Out[40]: 1
```

Yet another way to do this:

```
In [43]: Sum((0.5)**(n), (n, 1, float('inf'))).doit()
Out[43]: 1.00000000000000
```

To approximate, you can take a sufficiently large number instead of infinity:

```
In [51]: import sys

In [52]: Sum((0.5)**(n), (n, 1, sys.maxint)).doit()
Out[52]: 1.00000000000000
```

Comment: Use sys.maxsize instead of sys.maxint for python 3.x

Answer (score 2):

That's [a bug](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11642). It ought to work. In general, however, it's best to prefer exact rational numbers over floats in SymPy, wherever possible. If you replace `0.5` with `Rational(1, 2)` it works.